# Algebro-geometric proof of Cayley Hamilton theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I am looking for a reference on the algebro-geometric proof of C.H. Theorem:

> Every square matrix satisfies its characteristic polynomial.

There are several points I don`t understand reading my algebraic geometry notes. The proof uses ideas like Zariski topology. Is there a write-up of the proof from the required point of view? Please suggest if any.

Comment: Could you provide some more details on the proposed proof and where you're getting stuck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A detailed proof is given [here](https://www.aergus.net/blog/posts/using-zariski-topology-to-prove-the-cayley-hamilton-theorem.html), using Zariski topology. The key point is to consider $U:=\{A \in M_n(K) ∣A \text{ has $n$ distinct eigenvalues }\}$ in $X:=\{ A\in M_n(K)\mid \chi_A(A)=0\}$ in $K^{n^2}$. Since $K^{n^2}$ with the Zariski topology is an irreducible space, every non-empty open subset is dense in $K^{n^2}$. Now $U$ is an open subset.